# How to run the second line first and then the first line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have two log then I want first log(2) and then run log(1)

```
console.lo(1);
console.log(2);
```

END == > 2,1 in log

Comment: that's nice,tnks

Answer (score 2):

You should use promise and learn about it;

```js
 setTimeout(async () => {
       console.log(1)
      }, 100);
       console.log(2)
```

Comment: Why learn promise for this. You can just use setTimeout as you are using

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript works from top to bottom, the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is to change the positions

`console.lo(2); console.log(1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and run the callback function after a certain interval of time.

You should also see [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

```js
setTimeout(_ => console.log(1), 0);
console.log(2);
```